# CUBEVALUE formula: only 6 slicer filters?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Excel PowerPivot.  I have a CUBEVALUE formula in which I need to reference 7 slicers. The formula works if I list any 6 of the slicers, but when I add the 7th slicer it returns #N/A.  Anybody ever see that behavior or know why?

Comment: So I deleted one the slicers and the formulas were working fine.  But then the #N/A values came back!  And if I now reference any 5 of the 6 slicers it works. Very strange. Am thinking it must be an Excel bug??

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the number of slicers. More likely, your combination of slicers just results in "no data". You can test this by building a pivot table instead of CUBEVALUE and see if the same set of filters prodices a meaningful data set.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure something out. I had other measures showing as errors (I hadn't bothered with them until I could figure out why the CUBEVALUE formulas weren't working).  They were unrelated to the measures used in the CUBEVALUE formulas, but nevertheless once I fixed them the strange behavior went away. (Fingers crossed that it stays that way!).  I don't see why it would work for a while and then stop working - maybe something to do with calculation dependencies somehow(?).